# get_or_create not creating my object with attributes that I need

Tags: django

So I am attempting to get_or_create a conversation object. Now, if the object is already created, the code works fine. But if it's not created, it will create the conversation object, BUT not with the members that I am trying to pass. An empty conversation object. `members` is a manytomany field to User. What am I doing wrong here?

**views/message**

```
def message (request, profile_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()


            return redirect('dating_app:messages', profile_id)
    else:
        conversation, created = Conversation.objects.filter(members = request.user).filter(members= profile_id).get_or_create()


        other_user = conversation.members.filter(id=profile_id).get()

        form = MessageForm({'sender': request.user, 'conversation': conversation})

        context = {'form' : form, 'other_user': other_user }

        return render(request, 'dating_app/message.html', context)
```

**models.py/Conversation**

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out by using 'add()' to add my members after I created my object since it's a many to many field.

```
            conversation, created = Conversation.objects.filter(members = request.user).filter(members= profile_id).get_or_create()

            conversation.members.add(request.user, profile_id)
```